# SuperCMIT from Scheops 

Tags: microphone

Hi,

Just had a discussion with our local Nagra/Scheops supplier and he was raving about the new SuperCMIT shotgun microphone. It is currently been used here in the stadiums for the World Cup. There have been mixed reports about the quality of the mic and was just wondering if anyone has had the opportunity to use it? I am doing a trial run with it in a couple of weeks.